# Python Speed up JSON parsing - own decoder

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

i have big JSON lines file more than 100,000 lines (every line contains json data) like:

```
{"id": "000001", "Description" : "Description 0001", "state" : "development", "data" : { "ad1" : "Some data" , "ad2" : "Some data" }}
{"id": "000002", "Description" : "Description 0002", "state" : "development", "data" : { "ad1" : "Some data" , "ad2" : "Some data" }}
{"id": "000003", "Description" : "Description 0003", "state" : "approved", "data" : { "ad1" : "Some data" , "ad2" : "Some data" }}
{"id": "000004", "Description" : "Description 0004", "state" : "checking", "data" : { "ad1" : "Some data" , "ad2" : "Some data" }}
...
{"id": "00000n", "Description" : "Description 000n", "state" : "development", "data" : { "ad1" : "Some data" , "ad2" : "Some data" }}
```

At first step I want to decode only main attributes like 'id', 'Description' and 'state' and skip 'data' if possible because 'data' is e very big object
and the most of time takes to decode it. Without 'data' script is about 25x faster  :

```
import simplejson as json
with open('data.jsonl') as f:    
     for line in f:
         item = json.loads(line)
```

I've tried many json libraries and didn't get right performance.

Is it possible to write own decoder to skip some keys before they are processed ?

**Update 1**

I've made some tests with regex to cut some data before processing (as suggested in comments) but the processing tooks than 3 times longer as decode all data. So Regex is not an aption to do that....

Comment: If you just want these three keys, you can threat them just as string and use regex or your custom function to extract.

Comment: is data is the last item of the line?

Comment: I would "play" with `object_hook` of `json.loads()`. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load).

Comment: You can also try to remove data from line by regexp: `line = re.sub(r',?\s*"data"\s*:\s*\{.+?\}', '', line)`

Comment: `Free type + length`  and best performance ? Performance is not expected on objects that are not specific to the content and size. Best performance is achieved only if raw data is processed. If you have large capacity and different content, you can upgrade your system (hardware) for performance. It can be improved with your method, but it has nothing to do with the term performance. **Performance data is considered when writing, not while reading!**

Comment: *Is it possible to write own decoder... ?* **YES** of course. A dedicated parser is often more performant than a generic one, simply it only accept its dedicated input...

Comment: Please show the code you’re using to cut data with regex. It shouldn’t be three times slower. There’s likely a mistake.